# Javascript Dynamic Drop Down Menu - reactive on page reload?

Tags: php, javascript

My javascript isn't great, but I'm trying to learn. Been at this one for days now, relunctant to ask for help, but in need of a hint :)

I have a dropdown menu with two SELECT dropdowns.

```
    <select name="programSelect" onchange="setLanguage()" id="programList">
    </select>
  <br>
    <select name="languageSelect" id="languageList">
    </select>
```

Javascript (code to follow) creates the dropdowns from the XML.  It works great!

I'm now trying to accomplish a few simple things, starting with one item.

When I SUBMIT my form, it passes a variable via POST to the same page.  A search happens and the dropdown re-appear.

Since the onClick of the first dropdown makes the second dropdown populate, when the page reloads the dropdwons are't populated.  I did a not-so-great PHP hack which didn't really accomplish what I wanted.

Ideally when the page reloads I'd like the first dropdown to show all the choices (with the selected item SELECTED) and the second dropdown populated with the selected item SELECTED.

Code below. I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is simple or not...but thanks in advance.

This javascript in in my footer, and it loads a simple XML document that has the dropdown hierarchy already built. Javascript first, then XML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(init);
//var mainXML;
var curProgram="";
var curLanguage="";
function init(){
    // $("#languageList").hide();   //Dont Hide the level 2, or level 3
    loadXML("/xml/dropdownSelections.xml");
}
function loadXML(_xml){
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: _xml,
         dataType: "xml",
         success: setXML
}) // close ajax
}
function setXML(_xml){
var _idx=0;
var curOption;
var curCountry = $(_xml).find('country');
$(curCountry).each(function(i){
    var country = $(this);
    curOption=$("<option value='" + $(country).attr('program') + "'>" + country.children('label').text() + "</option>")
    $(curOption).appendTo($('#programList'))
})
}
function setLanguage(){
var curCountry = $('#programList').children(':selected').data('country')
$('#languageList').html(""); // reset the languages list
var curLang = $(curCountry).find('language');
$('#linkURL').html("");
if (curLang.length>1){
    curLang.each(function(i){
        var lang = $(this);
        var langCode=lang.attr('langCode');
        if (i==0){
            curOption="<option value='null'>--Select Issue--</option><option value='" + langCode + "'>" + lang.text() + "</option>";
        }else{
            curOption+="<option value='" + langCode + "'>" + lang.text() + "</option>"
        }
    });
    $(curOption).appendTo($('#languageList'));
    $('#languageList').show()
}else if (curCountry==null){
    // $('#languageList').hide();
    curOption="<option value='null'>--Select Issue--</option>";
    $(curOption).appendTo($('#languageList'));
}else{
    $('#languageList').hide();
    gotoPage($(curCountry).find('language').attr('langCode'))
}
}

</script>
```

And the XML (just the first part of it, there's other sections that mimic this structure):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<countries>
<country program="read-and-learn">
    <label>Read and Learn</label>

    <languages>
        <language langCode="italian">Italian</language>
        <language langCode="french">French</language>
        <language langCode="spanish">Spanish</language>
        <language langCode="german">German</language>
        <language langCode="japanese">Japanese</language>
        <language langCode="russian">Russian</language>
        <language langCode="dutch">Dutch</language>
    </languages>

</country>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this we want to persist select box selections between page submits. For this we can use PHP.

Whenever we submit any form containing form fields to a PHP page, we can access what actually selected in the PHP code.

So, in our case, to access the selected form field values in PHP we need to use the following code.

```
$programSelect = $_POST['programSelect'];
$languageSelect = $_POST['languageSelect'];
```

So, we have these values available in PHP.

When we need these values after page is loaded and select boxes are populated.

As JavaScript is in the same page, in JavaScript we add following two lines.

```
var programSelect = <?php echo $programSelect; ?>,
    languageSelect = <?php echo $languageSelect; ?>;
```

In the above two lines, we are passing the selected values from PHP to JavaScript.

Now, after populating the data from XML, now we need to select the options in select form fields. As we already have the selected options' values in JavaScript using simple jQuery, we can select them. For example :

```
$("#programList option[value='" + programSelect + "']").attr('selected', true);
$("#languageList option[value='" + languageSelect + "']").attr('selected', true);
```

This is just to give an idea.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the detailed response, trying it now.

Comment: I think I need to work with it. The theory above is straightforward but I must have done something wrong when I implemented.  I'm going to work with it and will post back my results and working code if/when.  Thanks a ton for help!!

Comment: I tried the above but must have made a mistake in my code.  The above answer was exactly what I was looking for and should work fine for someone else looking to do what I was working on.  Thanks Vanga!